# Matlab: using strfind to get exact match

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x5 cell which might look something like:

```
A = {'asd','pqr','asd 123','pqr123','asd 1','dfg',}
```

When I do:

```
strfind(A,'asd')
```

I get

```
[1]    []    [1]    []    [1]    []
```

However, I want an exact match. i.e. I desire

```
[1]    []    []    []    []    []
```

How do I achieve above ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use strcmp (case-sensitive) or strcmpi (case-insensitive).

```
strcmp(A,'asd');
```

gives the following ans:

```
1     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the return type to be a cell array, just like how `strfind` would, use:

```
regexp(A,['\<','asd','\>']);
```